# Nested sshpass for ssh with "-J" jump host option

Tags: ssh, password, sshpass

I have a script with ssh commands that are using a jump host:

```
scp -J user@jump file admin@server
ssh -J user@jump admin@server "touch hello"
```

I would like to ask for the passwords only once and tried `sshpass`:

```
sshpass -p "PasswordForJump" scp -J user@jump file admin@server
```

This will only ask the password for *admin@server*. However, since there are two ssh/scp commands, I still have to enter the admin password twice.

I tried to nest the `sshpass` but the script is blocked:

```
sshpass -p "PasswordForJump" sshpass -p "PasswordForServer" ssh -J user@jump admin@server
```

Naively I have tried to set the two passwords in a file (one per line) by expecting `sshpass` to use one after the other but this fail too.

Can I use `sshpass` to supply two passwords ?

Comment: Why you don't use `ssh-coy-id'' to connect passwordless? Then you can copy files [with pipes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/610135/209677)

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with the proxy command option:

```
> sshpass -p serverpassword ssh -oProxyCommand="sshpass -p gatewaypassword ssh -W %h:%p uname@gatewayserver" uname@targetserver
```

Answer (score 1):

```
env SSHPASS="JUMP_PASSWORD" \
  sshpass -d 123 ssh \
    -o ProxyCommand="sshpass -e ssh -W %h:%p JUMP_USER@JUMP_HOST" \
  TARGET_USER@TARGET_HOST \
  123<<<TARGET_PASSWORD
```

The above example is from my answer to a similar question in StackExchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597351/sshpass-with-ssh-j-jump-host/668489#668489

This example is more secure that using the `sshpass -p` option to pass in the password. Using the `-p` argument allows the password to be seen in the system process list. Using a combination of `-e` and `-d` will avoid that from occurring.

Comment: this proposition is interesting, but the question is about the use of scp not ssh. And with scp you can't use ProxyCommand.

Comment: "the question is also about the use of scp not only ssh"